# Why "this" becomes null in callback function?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this1: ', this);
    this.dbService.chats$.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log('this2: ', this);
    });
}
```

First console.log has all fields of Component while the 2nd console log has *null*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below code:-

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this1: ', this);
    this.dbService.chats$.on('value',(snapshot) => {
        console.log('this2: ', this);
    });
}
```

This is due to the fact that `this` now refers to the context within the `function`. But when you use the fat arrow `=>` `this` then refers to the outer environment.

Comment: I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 6):

In **anonymous function** or a **callback function**, this refers to the current context.

So in your example, it is referring to a context under the callback function.

**So the question is how to access outer `this`.**

There are two ways how you can access outer `this`.

> **1. Arrow function:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this1: ', this);
    this.dbService.chats$.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log('this2: ', this);
    });
}
```

> **2. Using bind:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this1: ', this);
    this.dbService.chats$.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log('this2: ', this);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are calling an anonymous function, to maintain the instance of `this` , use **arrow function**

> Instead of

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this1: ', this);
    this.dbService.chats$.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log('this2: ', this);
    });
}
```

> Use

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this1: ', this);
    this.dbService.chats$.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log('this2: ', this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some Time it may happen that under the function the **Context** of **This** not Available.
See **This** is a special Keyword the usage of this is all depend on how/where and when you use with function.

Try the below change Hope it may solve your problem.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this1: ', this);
    let that = this;       // you can give any name to variable.
    that.dbService.chats$.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log('this2: ', that);
    });
}
```